# Trying to assign a value to the i-th position of the slopes array. The error suggests that the index i is out of bounds for the slopes array

Tags: python, indexing

I am confused by the differences in my code and why the second method works. Here is my first method.

```
def calculate_slope(Mars_lobes, Mars_Flow_direction):
    df = Mars_lobes
    slopes = np.zeros(len(df))
    for i in df.index:
        x2 = np.max(df['distances'][i])
        x1 = np.min(df['distances'][i])
        y2 = np.max(df['elevations'][i])
        y1 = np.min(df['elevations'][i])
        slopes[i] = np.abs((y2 - y1)) / np.abs((x2 - x1))

    return slopes
```

I get an IndexError, which indicates that you're trying to access an index that's out of bounds for the array.

So how does this method fix that

```
def calculate_slope(df, Mars_Flow_direction):
    slopes = []
    for i in df.index:
        x2 = np.max(df['distances'][i])
        x1 = np.min(df['distances'][i])
        y2 = np.max(df['elevations'][i])
        y1 = np.min(df['elevations'][i])
        slope_value = np.abs((y2 - y1)) / np.abs((x2 - x1))
        slopes.append(slope_value)
    return np.array(slopes)
```

I got the code to work but don't understand the syntax behind it

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happened.  Please post the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over DataFrame indexes and using them as an index value for array assignment.

If you have a DataFrame with 3 rows, which have indexes 100, 200, 300 respectively, then `slopes` will be an numpy array of length 3, but `i` in for loop will hold value 100, 200 and 300 in each iteration.

So when you did `slopes[i] = np.abs((y2 - y1)) / np.abs((x2 - x1))`, you're actually doing `slopes[100] = np.abs((y2 - y1)) / np.abs((x2 - x1))` when 100th index does not exists in array with length of 3.

In 2nd approach, you're adding elements in a list on demand without using -index, hence it's working.